# Is there a way to access variables that are only defined some of the time?

Tags: javascript, cordova

This is with 'use strict' javascript, so it's not as lax with undeclared variables. My code looks like this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp').factory('factoryName', function(){
   var plugins = cordova.require('cordova/plugin_list').metadata;
   ...
});
```

The issue I have is that the variable `cordova` is only defined some of the time, which causes a runtime error when it isn't. When my app is built + run on a mobile device with cordova, `cordova` is obviously defined so it runs fine - but it's also run on browser without cordova, which causes crashing when the code block above runs.

Is there a way around this? Like maybe to check if `cordova` is declared before using it? The issue is that the error that gets thrown is from an undeclared variable, rather than from reading a property of undefined, so doing `if (cordova) {...}` will still fail. Or is there a different way to use cordova without referencing it like this?

Answer (score 3):

I would do `if (typeof cordova !== 'undefined')`:

```js
if (typeof cordova !== 'undefined') {
    console.log('hello');
}
console.log('it didnt crash');
```